# error while entering super user mode

Tags: sudo, users, groups

I would like to install git but when I type the command:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

I am getting the error:

```
iiit is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

The output of `groups` is:

```
iiit adm dialout cdrom dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `groups`

Comment: The problem is that you're not in the `sudo` group. Try `pkexec whoami`, and see if you can run the command. If you can, you can simply run `pkexec adduser "$USER" sudo` to fix this. Otherwise you'll have to reboot in the recovery mode and add your user to the `sudo` group from the recovery mode's root shell.